# Search for nodes by name in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I'm trying to find a node by name in an XmlDocument with the following code:

```
private XmlNode FindNode(XmlNodeList list, string nodeName)
{
    if (list.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (XmlNode node in list)
        {
            if (node.Name.Equals(nodeName)) return node;
            if (node.HasChildNodes) FindNode(node.ChildNodes, nodeName);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I call the function with:

```
FindNode(xmlDocument.ChildNodes, "somestring");
```

For some reason it always returns null and I'm not really sure why. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Not just XmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName(nodeName) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line:

```
if (node.HasChildNodes) FindNode(node.ChildNodes, nodeName);
```

to:

```
if (node.HasChildNodes)
{
    XmlNode nodeFound = FindNode(node.ChildNodes, nodeName);
    if (nodeFound != null)
        return nodeFound;
}
```

EDITED: the code is more correct now (tested) ;)

Comment: Thanks, dude. Kind of stupid that I missed something so simple.

Comment: Sometimes the more you check the code, the less you succeed in fixing it... :D

Comment: One additional question: if I have an XML structure with multiple paths ie:

<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
  </b>
  <d>
    <e/>
  </d>
</a>

it only seems to navigate the first tree (to c), but it doesn't find e with the above method. Is this expected behavior with my code?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read well your comment. I've edited the post, now it's more correct (and I've tested it too with your sample)

Comment: Anyway I still suggest you to check if XPath navigation fits your needs http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333
Or maybe LINQ to XML

Answer (score 21):

Why can't you use

```
Node.SelectSingleNode(".//" + nodeName)
```

?

Comment: You might get exception if there's any namespace defined in yr xml already:
Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.