# How to declare and handle dynamicaly lists of lists in C# 1.1

Tags: c#, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

I have a custom class named *CatalogItem* which I receive in a method, as an arrayed parameter.

Based upon one of the properties of these elements must assemble a matrix that the method returns.

```
public CatalogItem[][] ReorderCatalogItems(CatalogItem[] items)
```

The properties

```
public string Id
public string Version
public bool HasVersion
public bool HasDependencies
public string Name
public string DisplayName
public bool IsExportable
public string CatalogName
public string ZipName
```

But Visual Studio 2003 is not 2005, 2008 or 2010. It's been some time since I coded in this framework (1.1) for the last time.

I have this, since List and generics do not exist

```
StringBuilder zipNames = new StringBuilder();

foreach(CatalogItem item in items)
{
    if(item.ZipName != string.Empty && zipNames.ToString().IndexOf(item.ZipName) == -1)
    {
        zipNames.Append(item.ZipName);
        zipNames.Append("\r\n");
        //StringBuilder.AppendLine(string) is unexistent in fwk 1.1
    }
}

//SplitString is a custom method that does a string.Split with a string parser (unexistent out-of-the-box feat. in 2003)
string[] sZipNames = SplitString(zipNames.ToString(),"\r\n");

CatalogItem[][] orderedItems = new CatalogItem[sZipNames.Length+1][];
///+1 since string.Empty is one of the valid elements 
/// even when not listed on zZipNames (name default)

foreach(CatalogItem item in items)
{
    int i = 0;
    bool Next = true;
    while(Next)
    {
        if(item.ZipName == string.Empty)
        {
            //I'm out of ideas now
        }
        if(sZipNames[i].IndexOf(item.ZipName) == -1)
        {
            //I'm out of ideas now
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

@Edit:
oh for further understanding, this is my real and last objective: create an xml with this format. I've developed an XMLDoc Method todo so, but I need to create a control break iteration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<export>
<items outputfile="c:\data\erase\exportbatch.zip">
        <item>
            <catalog>operations</catalog>                                          
            <id>Od4f0f211-4673-49cd-a197-567768b9c00a</id>    
            <name>NewOp</name>                                 
            <dependencies>false</dependencies>
        </item>
        <item>
            <catalog>operations</catalog>                                          
            <id>Oc19efe25-33ec-45b7-9cc1-a813ffbecc61</id>    
            <name>TestAttributes</name>                                                                     
        </item>
    </items>
    <items outputfile="c:\data\erase\exportbatch2.zip">
        <item>
            <catalog>transactions</catalog>                                          
            <id>T15454fe0-7afb-4146-9ec3-83547f96b25a</id>    
            <name>GetAllEmployee</name>
            <dependencies>true</dependencies>
        </item>
        <item>
            <catalog>transactions</catalog>                                          
            <id>Tc37afa55-39e4-416d-9088-011a117cff72</id>    
            <name>CustOrderHist_Test123</name>                    
            <dependencies>false</dependencies>
        </item>
    </items>
</export>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET 1.1 you'd basically have to use `ArrayList` where each element is an `ArrayList` if you want "fully" dynamic sizes. It's a pain, and involves casting all over the place, but such is life.

In this case I'm not sure you actually need that though - it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but if you *actually* know the size of the "outer" array you could just build up an `ArrayList` for each item, then use:

```
CatalogItem[] subArray = (CatalogItem) list.ToArray(typeof(CatalogItem));
orderedItems[index] = subArray;
```

to convert that list to an array, and store it in the "outer" array.

Hope that helps - sorry not to be able to give more complete code, but as I say it's not clear to me what *exactly* you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is most useful. I've also edited (added my final purpose) to get a more accurate help, so feel free to propose another solution to this matter if you think that is better.

Comment: @apacay: Okay, it's not clear to me why you don't just add to the XmlDocument as you go. Why do you need the intermediate results?

Comment: because.. Wouldn't I be doing a search of the attribute on each item I'm adding?, and if it's the same whether you do this or not (because you have to do it anyways)... I still have to check if the item node already exists and not write it if it already exists, and I don't remember how to do that on an XmlDoc, I would have to search a bit more... Do you think it's worth the search?

Comment: You are rightas usual, I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/q/2797238/684646 so this is great news.

Comment: @apacay: I have to say I didn't follow all of that (I still haven't really got my head round what you're trying to achieve) - but it sounds like you've got an answer :)

Comment: Please excuse my language, English isn't native for me. I meant that, if operating with an XmlDoc (search attr, search nodes, do Ins-or-Upd stuff) is something easy to achieve then sign me up for it. It seemed easier for me to make a single pass over the XML with an XmlTextWriter or something like that.

Comment: @apacay: It may well be a lot more *efficient* to do it another way - but I'm afraid it's late and I haven't the energy to look into it in detail at the moment. If the *simple* approach of using the XML is fast enough, I'd go for it :)