# How can I make sure that there are no double entries in my XML File?

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I have a Save Button that loads Student Data into a Xml File, however right now you can just click the Save Button multiple times and make as many copies as you wish.

How can I prevent that from happening? If possible I'd like to limit the ID only, so there can't be two students with the same ID.

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(FilePath);
        XmlNode Student = doc.CreateElement("Student");

        XmlNode ID = doc.CreateElement("ID");
        ID.InnerText = txtStudentID.Text;
        Student.AppendChild(ID);

        XmlNode FirstName = doc.CreateElement("FirstName");
        FirstName.InnerText = txtFirstName.Text;
        Student.AppendChild(FirstName);

        XmlNode LastName = doc.CreateElement("LastName");
        LastName.InnerText = txtLastName.Text;
        Student.AppendChild(LastName);

        doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Student);
        doc.Save(FilePath);
```

I tried using something like this, but I cant use Descendants because I'm working with XmlDocuments and not XDocuments.

```
bool userExistsAlready = doc.Descendants("Student")
                             .Elements("ID")
                             .Any(x => x.Value == txtStudentID.Text);
```

Comment: navigate to a different page? Disable the Save-Button once it was clicked?

Comment: That wouldn't stop someone to make a new entry later with the same ID. The ID should always be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that the id value is in the file like this:

```
    private bool IsIdExistsInFile(XmlDocument doc, string id)
    {
        bool result = false;

        XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("xml/Student");

        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
            if (xn["ID"].InnerText == id)
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And you can check that the id value is in the file before save:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(FilePath);

        if (!IsIdExistsInFile(doc, txtStudentID.Text))
        {
            XmlNode Student = doc.CreateElement("Student");

            XmlNode ID = doc.CreateElement("ID");
            ID.InnerText = txtStudentID.Text;
            Student.AppendChild(ID);

            XmlNode FirstName = doc.CreateElement("FirstName");
            FirstName.InnerText = txtFirstName.Text;
            Student.AppendChild(FirstName);

            XmlNode LastName = doc.CreateElement("LastName");
            LastName.InnerText = txtLastName.Text;
            Student.AppendChild(LastName);

            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(Student);
            doc.Save(FilePath);
        }
```

Comment: That perfectly solves my Problem! Thank you very much Hidayet :)

Answer (score 0):

I took my answer from May 5.   Use GroupBy and then first like code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            Students students = new Students();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Students));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, students);

            students.students = students.students.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

        }

        public class Students
        {
            [XmlElement("Students")]
            public List<Student> students { get; set; }

        }
        public class Student
        {
            //Eigenschaften
            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public decimal Age { get; set; }
            public decimal Height { get; set; }
            public string Schoolclass { get; set; }
            public string Gender { get; set; }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm using another code to save to the xml file
```XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(FilePath);
            XmlNode Student = doc.CreateElement("Student");

            XmlNode ID = doc.CreateElement("ID");
            ID.InnerText = txtStudentID.Text;
            Student.AppendChild(ID);```

Comment: it is similar code. : doc.Descendants("Student").GroupBy(x => (string)(x.Element("ID")).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

Comment: I found similar link . try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797238/search-for-nodes-by-name-in-xmldocument